# Drawing to transparent destination causes drawing artifacts

Tags: cocoa

I have `NSWindow`:

```
_window = [[NSWindow alloc] init];
[_window setOpaque:NO];
[_window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[_window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```

And I have as its content view my custom view (without layer):

```
[_window setContentView:[[MyCustomView alloc] init]];
```

In `drawRect:` of my custom view I create bezier path that looks like system popup and fill with color.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [super drawRect:self.bounds];
    NSBezierPath *path = [self bodyShape];
    [self.backgroundColor setFill];
    [path fill];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

and all looks great [image: first time popover shows] 
until I move popover place indicator. After redrawing in window appears artifacts, while `drawRect:` of my custom view draws content right[image: drawing with artifacts].
And when I draws content next time, this white triangle (see picture above) stay in same place in window and moves with window.[image: Artifact moves with window]
If I add to my view layer - all appears to be ok, but I can't add a layer.
If I fill my view with some solid color, there are no artifact.[image: Fill with solid color]
I suggest that Cocoa caches first bitmap. But I do not sure why this happens and how to fix this. Maybe someone know why how fix to it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! The problem is that the window caches shadow around place indicator. I fix it with calling `invalidateShadow` method of `NSWindow`.